# Unable to find 'Message Body' TextBox. ‘Search Criteria’ did not match. (TYPE_1001)

Tags: automationanywhere

Hi I'm working on email object cloning.  The error is:

> Unable to find 'Message Body' TextBox. ‘Search Criteria’ did not match. (TYPE_1001)
>
> An error occurred at line number 8 of Task 'EmailPractice'. Open the
> Task in Workbench to view action at line number 8.

Comment: Provide more info, what is your search criteria? can you share the website as well?

Comment: Seems like the criteria you used to create object cloning are not valid anymore, I mean they are changing dynamically( witch each refresh) and you "hard code" them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to touch a server? Or object clone something that is in a web browser email client like Gmail or Yahoo?

If it's the server, that's really easy you can use the $Email Message$ variable and it auto-magically pulls the body of the email as it loops through an email server.

Something that is going to generate dynamically like a browser is gonna be tough, but you might be able to do something like that in gmail or something by turning the page to "html only" mode.  Good luck!